# Union and intersection of 2 sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can any help with kind of questions :

Let $A = \{ (2a,a) \,|\, a \in \mathbb{R}\}$, $B = \{ (b,b) \,|\, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Find $A \cup B$ and $A \cap  B$.

I guess $A \cap B = \{(d,d)\, |\, d \in (0,1)\}$ or something like this.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Try to draw the graphs of these relations. These are two lines.

Comment: $d=1/2$ is in $(0,1)$. Are you suggesting that if $d=1/2$ then $(d,d)$ is in $A$?

Comment: Instead of guessing, how about using the definitions to determine the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be reformulated using straight lines in a cartesian plane.

$A$ corresponds to the line $y_1=0.5x$ and $B$ corresponds to the line $y_2=x$.

Then $A \cap B$ is the intersection of these: $y_1 = y_2 \leftrightarrow 0.5x = x$ with the only solution $x=0$. Hence $A \cap B = {(0,0)}$.

The union $A \cup B$ is trivially stated.

Comment: Thanks first , but for A∩B={(d,d)|d∈(0)} it is okay using lines , how about A∩B ? how can write it in the correct annotation ?

Comment: I assume you mean $A \cup B$.

Comment: The only overlapping element is $(0,0)$, otherwise everything in $A$ or $B$ is in the union.

Comment: sorry I meant A∪B, how can I express it in set notation ?